# BackgroundDownloader 4GB Limit

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-mobile, uwp

I'm using a BackgroundDownloader in a C# UWP app and it appears that on Windows 10 Mobile it has a 4GB limit (binary GB, so about 4.2 decimal GB).  Files in the same directory work as long as they are not bigger than 4GB, tried a 3.99 and it was fine, a 4.04GB did not download.  BackgroundDownloader is not returning any errors (which work on other files) nor is it provisioning the temp download file.

I do have plenty of space on the SD card, it's a 32GB card that was empty, and after not being able to download the 4.04 I was able to download 2 files totaling over 7GB, so not a space issue.

Is there a way to change that limit, or at least some documentation that the limit exists?  I've dug through MSDN looking for confirmation of the limit without success.

Comment: Not have worked with UWP yet, but 4 GB is a limit in the filesystem FAT32 for example. Do you use it by chance?

Comment: It is fat32, thanks, I didn't even think of that.  If you could post an answer of that I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum size of a file depends on the filesystem.

As pointed out in the comments, the root of the problem is the `FAT32` filesystem, which has a maximum filesize of `4 GiB - 1 Byte`.

Consider using the `NTFS` filesystem.

```
File System |       Max Size
____________________________
FAT32       | 4 GiB − 1 Byte
NTFS        |         16 TiB
```